# Libtiff dependancy fails when installing wine with homebrew OSX 10.12.3

Tags: macos, homebrew, wine, libtiff

I am trying to install wine through homebrew. When its installing the dependancies, the libtiff fails because the source package url is not found and whole installer quits. I installed libtiff seperately and then tried, still this problem occurs. Any workaround ?

```
Rangarajans-MBP:homebrew-core ranga$ brew install wine
==> Installing dependencies for wine: libtiff, gd, libgphoto2, little-cms2, cmake, jasper, libicns, makedepend, openssl, net-snmp, sane-backends, libtasn1, gmp, nettle, libunistring, libffi, p11-kit, gnutls
==> Installing wine dependency: libtiff
==> Using the sandbox
==> Downloading http://download.osgeo.org/libtiff/tiff-4.0.7.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/debian/pool/main/t/tiff/tiff_4.0.7-4.debian.tar.xz

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Trying a mirror...
==> Downloading https://mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/t/tiff/tiff_4.0.7-4.debian.tar.xz

curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Error: Failed to download resource "libtiff--patch"
Download failed: https://mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/t/tiff/tiff_4.0.7-4.debian.tar.xz
Rangarajans-MBP:homebrew-core ranga$
```

Comment: `brew update` may solve the problem. See https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/3264

Comment: Did brew update, brew cleanup , cleared the cache.. and still same issue. Have posted the same in their git. thanks for redirecting there

Comment: ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/t/tiff/tiff_4.0.7-4.debian.tar.xz has been replaced with ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/t/tiff/tiff_4.0.7-5.debian.tar.xz, `brew update` will not work until that reference has been updated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/t/tiff/tiff_4.0.7-4.debian.t‌​ar.xz` has been superseded by `ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/t/tiff/tiff_4.0.7-5.debian.t‌​ar.xz`. If you compare the files, there's an extra CVE patch added.

To get homebrew to install wine, patch the libtiff formula to use the updated Debian package:

1. Open `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/libtiff.rb`
2. Patch the following lines so it looks like this: https://gist.github.com/georghendrik/c649b62c017c89980ec6fcad31513510

   - `url "https://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/debian/pool/main/t/tiff/tiff_4.0.7-5.debian.tar.xz"`
   - `sha256 "f4183c48ed74b6c3c3a74ff1f10f0cf972d3dba0f840cf28b5a3f3846ceb2be6"`
   - `"patches/16-CVE-2016-10094.patch",` (note the comma)
   - `"patches/17-CVE-2017-5225.patch"`
3. Run `brew install wine`. Homebrew will update itself and stash your work.
4. Run `cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/; git stash pop`
5. Run `brew install wine` again.

Comment: 3. cd /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/; git commit -a 
4. brew install wine